# Чтение текстового файла в динамический двумерный массив. Си

Tags: c, файлы, динамические-массивы

Основная проблема ставится следующим образом: есть текстовый файл с некоторым числом строк, в которых содержится некоторое число символов. Нужно считать текст из файла и записать его в двумерный массив. Написал код, однако в нем есть проблемы:

```
    int main()
    {
    char **arr;
    int flag,i,j;
    int buffer;
    int * num;
    int n1, n2,str;
    n1 = n2 = str = i = j = flag = 0;
    FILE * text = fopen("C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\test.txt", "r");
    if (!text) return -1;
    rewind(text);
    str = num_str(text);
    arr = (char **)malloc((str + 1) * sizeof(char *));
    num = (int*) malloc((str + 1) * sizeof(int));
    rewind(text);
    while (!feof(text)) {
        buffer = fgetc(text);
        n1++;
        if (buffer == '\n') {
            num[i] = n1;
            i++;
            n1 = 0;
        }
    }
    num[str] = n1;
    rewind(text);
    // for (i = 0; i <= str; i++) printf("%i\n", num[i]);
    for (i = 0; i <= str; i++) arr[i] = (char *)malloc(num[i] * (sizeof(char*)));
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (!feof(text)) {
        buffer = fgetc(text);
        arr[i][j] =(char) buffer;
        j++;
        if (buffer == '\n') i++;
    }
    printf("%c", arr[0][6]);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

При чтении первой строки массива всё хорошо, выводится то что должно выводиться. Однако при выведение символов следующей строки ( к примеру arr[1][2]) там хранится какой-то непонятный мусор. num_str - функция которая возвращает число символов '\n' в текстовом файле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка здесь

```
while (!feof(text)) {
    buffer = fgetc(text);
    arr[i][j] =(char) buffer;
    j++;
    if (buffer == '\n') i++;
}
```

Когда вы достигли конца строки, нужно не только увеличить номер строки, но и сбросить номер столбца

```
if (buffer == '\n') {
  i++;
  j = 0;
}
```

Comment: Вот что значит глаз замылился. Большое спасибо!